# Ionic radio button checked

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a simple radio group as follows which cover a range of checkbox items on the pade:

```
<ion-list radio-group>
      <ion-list-header>School</ion-list-header>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label color="dark">Select all</ion-label>
          <ion-radio (click)="resetFilters()" value="always" checked></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label color="dark">Clear all</ion-label>
          <ion-radio (click)="unsetFilters()" value="locked"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

The radio checkbox is set to default to "Select all" and if I click "Clear all" then all the checkbox items on my page become uncheck - so this all works fine. The issue is when I navigate away from the page and return, the radio button tick is back on "Select all", but it should be on "Clear all". I've tried to get it so it should be on the last selected option.. can someone point me the right way?

Answer (score 0):

set global variable resetFilterCalled = true if resetAll() function called, and check this variable in page constructor method.